# How to access Static string in the Sealed Class

Tags: vb.net

Following is a sealed class. How can I access the method in that class?

```
Public NotInheritable Class ConnectionStringProvider
    Public Shared Function GetConnectionString() As String
        Dim tReturn As String = ""
        Try
            tReturn = _ConnectionString
        Catch
        Finally
        End Try
        Return tReturn
    End Function
End Class
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can't inherit a static/Shared member so what does sealed/NotInheritable have to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the class name and function name :

```
Dim ConString As String = ConnectionStringProvider.GetConnectionString()
```

If this does not satisfy your query then please elaborate on your question.

Comment: code would be better as `Dim conString = ConnectionStringProvider.GetConnectionString()` IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it. I dont think that there is a problem with that.

This is what I did with an example.

```
sealed class Example
{
    public static void GetStringValue()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside Example");
    }
}
```

and called it with the name of the class i.e., in this case it is Example

So :

`Example.GetStringValue()` will Yield me

Inside Example

Is this what you wanted to say ?